# Assing first selectbox's value to second with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to assign first selectbox value to second on selection...

```
<select name="first">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<select name="second">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

User enters site then selects from first selectbox, same time second selectbox must have same value but if user wants he also must be select from second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name="first"], select[name="second"]').change(function () {
            $('select[name="first"], select[name="second"]').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2aa9yt4m/

use the above code, for assigning value to selection boxes. whenever changed.

Comment: alright it works but with select2 plugin doesnt see value on the page

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name="first"], select[name="second"]').change(function () {
            $('select[name="second"]').val($('select[name="first"]').val())
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body><select name="first">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<select name="second">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actualy works but, cannot see on page.. when i hit the second selectbox i see it selected but cannot seen in page

Comment: do u want to keep the first select value on second select on changing the second also???

Comment: Yes alright, and it works but second selecbox seems empty. if you want to see value, you have to hit it.

Comment: alright it works but with select2 plugin doesnt see value on the page